# Generate coordinate based on random angle from original coordinate in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, coordinate

I have the coordinates of the original position (x,y). I have to move at a fixed distance R from this point at a random angle between 0-360degree. How do i do this in MATLAB.

I am not looking to plot this, but just generate the new coordinate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angle = 360*rand; % random angle between 0-360
[xv,yv] =pol2cart(angle*pi/180,R); % convert polar coordinates to cartersian
% add vector (xv, yv) to original coordinates
x2 = x + xv;
y2 = y + yv;
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the Mapping Toolbox, then you can use `angle * pi / 180` instead of `deg2rad(angle)`.

Answer (score -2):

This is barely a MATLAB question

x2=x1*cos(theta)
y2=y1*sin(theta)

if your theta is in degrees, then use sind and cosd

Comment: **Random**... the key is... **random**